# Raspberry-Pi default route automaticly removed

Tags: routing, raspberry-pi, wireless-access-point

I create an access point on wlan0_ap and share an Internet connection on wlan0.
I create a systemd unit file for this.
Before running dnsmasq (my last daemon, launched in the foreground), I see with '`ip r`' my default route added, but after a few moments, the default route is removed. No messages in /var/log/syslog, /var/log/messages, journalctl ... I tried to disable the network and dhcpcd services at startup but nothing works.

I connect my wlan0 interface manually:

```
hostapd -B -ddd /etc/hostapd.conf
wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c /home/pi/wpa_supplicant.conf
dhclient -4 -cf /home/pi/dhcpc.conf wlan0
And then I start the DNS / DHCP service of the AP (dnsmasq)
```

I tried this, but this did not solve my problem

```
dhclient ...
ip r add default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0
```

I use, in my systemd unit file:

```
[unit]
Wants = network.target
After = network.target
```

I also tried to disable all services (avahi, network, networking, network-online, network-pre, systemd-networkd-online, dhcpcd ....) that could update the routing table ...

Can someone help me understand please? Thank you

Comment: Wait, you're using `wlan0` as the client _and_ as access point?

Comment: No, wlan0 for client (type managed) and wlan0_ap (type master), thank's for your interest.